# Assign a path name to variable

Tags: excel, vba

I need to assign a path name to a variable.

Below is my code. The variable that I have to assign the path is `strFile`.

```
Sub onglet()
     
    Dim sourceworkbook As Workbook
    Dim currentworkbook As Workbook
 
    Set currentworkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Set sourceworkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Pooryavirsingh.Soond\Documents\Knowings 
    Box\Extraction_Factures_En_Circulation\" & strFile & "\")

    sourceworkbook.Sheets("Autres").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
     
    sourceworkbook.Sheets("Hotline").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
    sourceworkbook.Sheets("DII").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
    sourceworkbook.Sheets("CSC").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")

    sourceworkbook.Sheets("Fibres").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
    sourceworkbook.Sheets("Prescripteurs").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
 
    sourceworkbook.Sheets("Achats").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
 
    sourceworkbook.Sheets("Analyse").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
    sourceworkbook.Sheets("Pivot_2").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
 
    sourceworkbook.Sheets("Pivot").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
      
    sourceworkbook.Close
 
    Set sourceworkbook = Nothing
    Set currentworkbook = Nothing
 
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
 
    Worksheets("Liste des frs critiques").Activate
    Worksheets("Liste des frs critiques").Range("A1").Select
     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best to define the root directory as a Const.  This will make your code easier to read and debug.  You problem is that your code has an extra "" after the file name.

```
Const FilePath = "C:\Users\Pooryavirsingh.Soond\Documents\Knowings Box\Extraction_Factures_En_Circulation\"

If Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Directory:" & vbNewLine & FilePath, vbCritical, "Invalid Directory"
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim strFile As String
strFile = "testexcel.xlsm"

Dim FullFileName As String
FullFileName = FilePath & strFile

 If Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid File Name:" & vbNewLine & FullFileName, vbCritical, "File Not Found"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Where is `strFile` defined and set?  What is the value of `strFile`?

Comment: the value of strFile is testexcel.xlsm

Comment: @gpolimited I updated my answer to include tests for the directory and file name.

Comment: the filename is not fixed as the filename maybe like testexcel170820.xlsm like date now

Comment: @gpolimited are you trying to iterate over the files in a directory?

Comment: i mean each week there will be a file like for the last week it will have to take testexcel100820.xlsm but for today it has to take testexcel170820.xlsm

Comment: @gpolimited You need to supply a valid file name.  The code is not going to guess for you.  You can use `DIr()` to search for files that follow a pattern(see [VBA DIR Function – ).How to Use in Excel](https://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-dir-function/).

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code.

```
Sub onglet()

Dim filter As String, caption As String
Dim sourceFilename As String
Dim sourceworkbook As Workbook, currentworkbook As Workbook

Set currentworkbook = ThisWorkbook
    
    'Get the Source workbook
    filter = "Excel and CSV Files (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.csv),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.csv"
    caption = "Please Select an input file "
    sourceFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)
    
    Set sourceworkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(sourceFilename)
    'Using foregoing code you would be able to select source file as & when required, without need to manually write the file name here in script.

     'Your sheets' Copy & Paste operation starts from here
     sourceworkbook.Sheets("Autres").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
     
     sourceworkbook.Sheets("Hotline").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
     sourceworkbook.Sheets("DII").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
     sourceworkbook.Sheets("CSC").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
 

     sourceworkbook.Sheets("Fibres").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
     sourceworkbook.Sheets("Prescripteurs").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
 
     sourceworkbook.Sheets("Achats").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
 
     sourceworkbook.Sheets("Analyse").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
     sourceworkbook.Sheets("Pivot_2").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
 
     sourceworkbook.Sheets("Pivot").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("Liste des frs critiques")
 
 
     sourceworkbook.Close
 
     Set sourceworkbook = Nothing
     Set currentworkbook = Nothing
 
     ThisWorkbook.Activate
 
     Worksheets("Liste des frs critiques").Activate
     Worksheets("Liste des frs critiques").Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```